# plotting time with python

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a pandas data frame which looks something like this

[image]

I want to plot time on the `X-axis` and sales on the `Y-axis`. This is what I have tried so far.

```
ax = sns.scatterplot(x="Time", y="sales", data=df)
```

I am getting the error which says :

> cannot interpret input 'Time'

Comment: I can't reproduce this, even when the input time format is a string. Please create a minimal, compete, verifiable example.

Comment: Can you include the output of `print(df.head())` in the question? It will help us to determine the source of the error and how to resolve it

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the rest of your code, so the source of the error is not clear, but since the function seems to have a problem with the values in the x-axis, I suspect there is an issue with the format of those values. Please add the rest of your code so that I can get a clearer idea of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As said before in this thread, you need to format the x-axsis

```
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
times = ['01:00 AM','02:00 AM','03:00 AM','04:00 AM','05:00 AM']
sales = [256, 147, 478, 569, 147]
format = '%I:%M %p'
timesFormated =[]
for i in times:
    timesFormated.append(datetime.strptime(i, format))
plt.plot(timesFormated, sales)
plt.show()
```

---

## EDIT:

I noticed you mentioned you had a pada dataframe, so here is another option

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from pandas.plotting import register_matplotlib_converters
register_matplotlib_converters()

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'times':['01:00 AM','02:00 AM','03:00 AM','04:00 AM','05:00 AM'],
    'sales':[256, 147, 478, 569, 147]
})

print("Time column type before: ", df['times'].dtypes)        # EDIT 2
df['times'] = pd.to_datetime(df['times'],format='%I:%M %p' )  # EDIT 2
print("Time column type after: ", df['times'].dtypes)         # EDIT 2

plt.plot(df['times'], df['sales'])
plt.show()
```

---

## EDIT 2:

See my added 3 lines above, This gives the time column format before and after converting it:

```
>>>Time column type before:  object
>>>Time column type after:  datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: My time column has over 500 rows. So I cannot manually type all the rows.     `df2 = pd.DataFrame({'time':[df3['Time']],
                         'opens':[df3['sales']] 
                   })`  I did this to get all the data in the dataframe but I'm getting this error. # duplicate columns & possible reduce dimensionality

Comment: can you give an example of the structure of your dataframe. i.e. what do you get if you execute: `print(df3.head(1))`

Comment: @Afroboy23 , See my edit above. The time was converted from object to datetime.  What datatype is your dataframe time column? `print(df3['times'].dtypes)`

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['1:00 AM', 256], ['2:00 AM', 147], ['3:00 AM', 478], ['4:00 AM', 569], ['5:00 AM', 147]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Time', 'Sales'])
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = df['Time']
y = df['Sales']
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

The above code generates the following plot :-
[image: Time-Sales plot]

Comment: My dataframe has over 500 columns. So I cannot manually type all the rows. How would that change the code if all of my data is in the pandas dataframe?

Comment: If you already have the data in your data frame, then you just need to specify the columns you want, as x and y axes. And then plot. So, you can start from line no 5 of my code above. Hope this helps!